# Missing endcsname when passing command to hypersetup

Tags: hyperref, expansion, etoolbox

I'm trying to manually process a list of authors.
The logic works in the document, but not it does not seem to work when I pass it to hypersetup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Logic to process author list, e.g., part of some package %%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Define lists
\newcommand{\authlist}{}
\newcounter{nMYauthors}
\newcommand\MYauthor[2][]{\author[#1]{#2}\listadd{\authlist}{#2}\stepcounter{nMYauthors}}
%Define processing of list
\newcommand{\bodyforloop}[1]{\stepcounter{iMYauthor}\ifnumequal{\value{iMYauthor}}{1}{}{\ifnumequal{\value{nMYauthors}}{\value{iMYauthor}}{, and }{, }}#1}
\newcounter{iMYauthor}
\newcommand{\displayAuthorList}{\setcounter{iMYauthor}{0}\forlistloop{\bodyforloop}{\authlist}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Define authors in preamble %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\MYauthor[*]{Ms. F. First}
\MYauthor[*]{Mr. S. Second}
\affil[*]{\LaTeX amateurs}

%This generates errors
\hypersetup{pdfauthor = {\displayAuthorList}}

\begin{document}
The new author list works in the document: \displayAuthorList
\end{document}
```

The errors I get is: Missing endcsname when passing command to hypersetup

Anyone any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: `pdfauthor` has to expand to text, you can not increment counters.  or make other assignments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an expandable command.

For this application it makes sense to redefine `\author`.

I set up a (global) list management, that can be reused for other purposes. The `\delivergloballist` command takes as arguments the list name, the separator between only two elements, the separator between more than two elements and the separator for the last two elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Manage lists
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definegloballist}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_dikdirk_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtogloballist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_dikdirk_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\deliverlist}{mmmm}
 {
  \seq_use:cnnn { g_dikdirk_list_#1_seq } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definegloballist{authors}

\NewCommandCopy\authblkauthor\author
\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\authblkauthor{#2}}{\authblkauthor[#1]{#2}}%
  \addtogloballist{authors}{#2}%
}
%Define processing of list
\newcommand{\displayAuthorList}{%
  \deliverlist{authors}{ and }{, }{, and }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Define authors in preamble %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\author[*]{Mrs. F. First}
\author[*]{Mr. S. Second}
\affil[*]{\LaTeX amateurs}

\hypersetup{pdfauthor = {\displayAuthorList}}

\begin{document}

\title{Example paper}
\maketitle

The new author list works also in the document:

\displayAuthorList

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output of `pdfinfo` is

```
Title:
Subject:
Keywords:
Author:          Mrs. F. First and Mr. S. Second
Creator:         LaTeX with hyperref
Producer:        pdfTeX-1.40.25
CreationDate:    Thu May  4 16:05:47 2023 CEST
ModDate:         Thu May  4 16:05:47 2023 CEST
Custom Metadata: yes
Metadata Stream: no
Tagged:          no
UserProperties:  no
Suspects:        no
Form:            none
JavaScript:      no
Pages:           1
Encrypted:       no
Page size:       612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot:        0
File size:       46742 bytes
Optimized:       no
PDF version:     1.5
```